# Error show html form in all IE

Tags: css

I have a code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_body"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And css off style.css:

```
* {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#main_body {
    width: 568px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 295px;
    background: url(../images/form_BG.png) no-repeat left; 
}
```

When i run firefox is result is:
[image]

But when run in IE is result error show in left, not show in center as firefox
[image]

Comment: Nitpick: HTML is not 'code', it's 'markup'.

Comment: what about if you try something like this  `background: url(../images/form_BG.png) no-repeat center top;`

Answer (score 0):

`margin:auto` doesn't work well in IE. You can wrap the `#main_body` div with another div containing the style `text-align:center`. But this will center align all your texts inside the #main_body. So, add another `text-align` property inside `#main_body` to override.

i.e.
change the #main_body like:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
   <div id="main_body"></div>
</div>
```

and if you don't want the text inside #main_body to be center aligned, change the css like:

```
#main_body
{
   width: 568px;
   text-align: left;
   height: 295px;
   border:1px solid red;
   margin:auto;
   text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
}
#main_body {
width: 568px;
text-align: left;
height: 295px;   background: url(../images/form_BG.png) no-repeat left;    }
```

work in all browser

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Doctype to your page, for example, for Transitional XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

For XHTML it will be good to change the <html> opening tag to this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Comment: BTW, using the universal selector (a. k. a. "star") is very inefficient, you should avoid using it at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
}

body { text-align: center; }

#main_body {
width: 568px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: left;
height: 295px;
background: url(../images/form_BG.png) no-repeat left; 
}
```

The text-align property in the body tag will center the #main_body div in IE, then the text-align property inside the #main_body selector will reset the text alignment within #main_body

Answer (score -1):

Add this css:

```
#main_body {
    width: 568px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 295px;
    background: url(../images/form_BG.png) no-repeat; 
    margin: auto; 
}
```

See results of the above css in below images

Firefox:
[image]

IE:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't very explanatory, maybe... In any case, topicstarter's problem lies in missing DOCTYPE *only*, your totally correct margin: auto; gets ignored by IE because of this.